# OpenGL - select objects by mouse area

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I render a scene with objects by OpenGL. And I want to implement selection objects by mouse area.
Googling this question I got a few ideas on how it can be done.

1. glRenderMode and GL_SELECT - works properly but it's deprecated and it doesn't support in modern versions of OpenGL;
2. draw objects using colors as ids. It's a good decision if you want to pick one nearest object, but when we need to select many objects and select all objects inside an area it's not suitable.
3. Ray casting. It's hard to implement and also I have doubts about performance if we'll apply this method for an area and how it will work with a big amount of objects.

If you have experience of some implementation or any ideas share it, please.

Comment: 3 years ago, I was in a similar situation. I started with your 2. approach but I faced serious performance issues. Reading back the color buffer for mouse-click/pick evaluation seemed to stall my rendering. (Maybe, this could've been done more clever but I don't know how.) Hence, we switched to your 3. approach. I can confirm that this is much more implementation effort. Additionally, as this is done on CPU, there are less cores available for a potential concurrent evaluation. However, this is the way I would recommend. The advantage: CPU (for clicks) and GPU (rendering) can work concurrently.

Comment: _3. Ray casting. ... I have doubts about performance_ How many triangles do you expect? (average, guessed) Do you expect some hierarchical structure or any other organization of triangles to apply something like early-bail-out? With pre-intersection tests (mouse ray against bounding spheres), we are able to manage millions of triangles with a reasonable reaction time.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for your answer! If I understood correctly you did 3rd variant. How it works when the area is big( almost full screen )? As far I understand it cast one ray for each pixel in the area.

Comment: Ful screen is irrelevant. We build the ray cast converting the mouse screen pos. into 3d world pos. (The ray goes from eye position (camera origin) through this 3d pos.) Actually, we limit the ray to a segment from near to far clip plane to be precise. Then, we do segment<->bounding sphere tests. If this doesn't fail we do segment<->triangle tests i.e. more or less simple math. Sounds terrible but modern CPUs are not that bad to crunch numbers as you may afraid... ;-) That's why a proper organization of geo can safe a lot. Bounding sphere tests are really cheap.

Comment: Transformations (i.e. matrix multiplications) might cause a significant impact. To manage this, it would be fine if you limit transformations to translation and rotation (or, at least, to something which is easy and reliable to invert). In this case: Instead of transforming each individual vertex into world coordinates, you can transform the mouse segment into local coordinates (and convert the hit results back in case). That can save you a lot of transformations (to earn more performance).

Comment: @Scheff We build the ray cast converting the mouse screen pos
How to create a ray from a selected mouse area? I thought we create one ray for each selected pixel in the area

Comment: Don't you mixup ray-tracing with mouse clicking? For mouse-clicks, the ray-casting means that the mouse pointer casts a ray through 3d (like a shadow if the light source would be the eye). This ray is a geometry which can be intersected against your scene geometry (applying more or less simple geometry-algorithms). Hence, the term ray-casting... And, doing geometry intersection on CPU side, there are actually no pixels at all. ;-)

Comment: Do I mis-understand you? Is this a question about rubber-band selection?

Comment: I mean after mouse-clicking we cast a ray. When we have selected mouse area we should cast rays from each position of this area. Isn't it?

Comment: I don't know how others have done this. When I did rubber-band selection, I did it similar like ray-casting I described above. But, I use a [frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum) instead of a segment. The frustum is a sub-frustum of the view frustum with its base exactly the rubber-band rectangle from mouse drawing. The rest is similar like above. A frustum is a convex polytope with 6 faces (similar like a box but a bit oblique for perspective views). Bounding sphere checks and triangle checks are similar simple like for segment.

Comment: E.g. to find out whether a triangle is completly inside the frustum you just check whether all three vertices are in. Frustum<->point checks are usually done checking the points against the planes (of the 6 faces). (Hence, I mentioned that a frustum is convex.) Point<->plane checking is really cheap - something like a scalar product, a dot product and a vector subtraction.

Comment: Okey. Great thanks for the info!
Firstly, I need to implement single-click picking with ray casting after this, I'll learn about frustums and how it works. I don't expect it will be soon but I hope it will be done :)